# How send a binary file in segments over network in C?

Tags: c, sockets, binary, file-transfer

I am a bit puzzled over how to send a file from an http server to a client(web-browser).

First I send the header and my next task is to send the file content. However I want to send it in segments of say 512 bytes instead of the whole file at once as I ran into some problems.

I am a bit lost on how to achieve that. Here is what I want

```
read file1;
while (seg=get_next_segment(file1)){
  do
    send(seg)
  until (seg_is_sent)
}
```

However I can't seem to find the appropriate functions to achieve that. `fread` and `fseek` crossed through my mind but the first one reads the whole file at once and with fseek I don't see a way to just grab a portion from a file(instead of reading from the file pointer until the end of the file).

Comment: If `fread` reads the whole file at once, why does it have parameters telling it how much to read? And `fseek` can't be used for reading at all.

Comment: can I ask why do you want to send it in segments? Also, `sendfile` is a lot more efficient.

Comment: @yi_H the reason is that I sent it before as a whole and it didn't arrive as a whole. I was getting a message in the browser like "Could not read file"

Comment: @Joachim I think only people that already know how the functions work are able to read and fully understand some manpages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fread`does not read a whole file to the end.  It reads exactly how much you tell it to read.

```
size_t
 fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems,
     FILE *restrict stream);

 size_t
 fwrite(const void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems,
     FILE *restrict stream);
```

Both functions take a size and `nitems`.  You could set the size to 512, and the number of items to 1 (or vice versa) and read just that portion of the file.

Comment: Now I see that. However I am curious why the function is implemented as that instead of just giving right away the `number of bytes` to read.

Comment: A very common usage pattern is `fread(foo, sizeof(some_complex_datastructure_t), x, fp);`.  I'm not sure there's a sound technical reason, except that you're then talking about discrete elements rather than bytes.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page:

> `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`
>
> The function `fread()` reads *nmemb* elements of data, each *size* bytes long, from the stream pointed to by *stream*, storing them at the location given by *ptr*.

As you can see, you don't have to read the whole file with `fread`, you can read it in *nmemb* size chunks.

If you are writing your own web-server in C, you may want to have a look at [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/s/libmicrohttpd/), which is a web-server in C for embedding into other applications, it can handle streaming a file for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling kind... How about something like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    char buffer[512];
    size_t nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, fp);
    if (nread > 0)
        send_to_socket(buffer, nread);

    if (nread < 512)
    {
        if (feof(fp))
            printf("End of file\n");
        if (ferror(fp))
            printf("Error reading\n");
        break;
    }
}
```